# MySQL, php, android connectivity to get blob images

Tags: php, android, mysql, blob

I am able to get character data from MySQL database as shown in image below, but when i fetch BLOB image from database, it shows null value.

Can you please help me for this problem to fetch image from MySQL through PHP to ANDROID using Volley and display it in IMAGEVIEW

PHP

```
session_start();

define('DB_USER','********');

define('DB_PASSWORD','********');

define('DB_HOST','*******');

define('DB_NAME','*********');

$dbc=@mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD)or die(mysql_error());

//echo "database";

mysql_select_db(DB_NAME)or die(mysql_error());

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM disco_detail");

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))

{

$output[]=$row;

}

print(json_encode($output));
```

OUTPUT

> [{"disco_name":"Mocha Coffee & Conversations","disco_address":"28A, Defence Colony Market, New Delhi","disco_phone":"0","disco_offer":"30% off on Drinks","disco_city":"New Delhi","latitude":"28.531256","longitude":"77.146764","disco_image":null},{"disco_name":"Capitol","disco_address":"50-B, Ashok Hotel,Niti Marg, Chanakyapuri, New Delhi","disco_phone":"0","disco_offer":"10% discount on food","disco_city":"New Delhi","latitude":"28.597192","longitude":"77","disco_image":null},{"disco_name":"Kota House","disco_address":"Shahjahan Road, Khan Market, Lodhi Estate, New Delhi","disco_phone":"0","disco_offer":"Free Entry","disco_city":"New Delhi","latitude":"29","longitude":"77","disco_image":null},{"disco_name":"Etal","disco_address":"Level-II, MGF City Square Mall, Rajouri Garden, New Delhi","disco_phone":"0","disco_offer":"5% off on Bar","disco_city":"New Delhi","latitude":"29","longitude":"77","disco_image":""},{"disco_name":"Hookah","disco_address":"Basant Block, Vasant Vihar, New Delhi","disco_phone":"0","disco_offer":"20% off on Hookah","disco_city":"New Delhi","latitude":"29","longitude":"77","disco_image":""},{"disco_name":"DiscoTheque","disco_address":"Ranjit Avenue, Amritsar","disco_phone":"0","disco_offer":"Free Entry","disco_city":"Amritsar","latitude":"0","longitude":"0","disco_image":""},{"disco_name":"Kcet","disco_address":"Ranjit Avenue, Amritsar","disco_phone":"999999974","disco_offer":"750/750 Marks in Project","disco_city":"Amritsar","latitude":"0","longitude":"0","disco_image":""}]

Comment: You do need to actualy include the image, or better the code that's causing problems and any output it gives.

Comment: Please post the code you are using and what you tried.